# Android: "Socket Not Connected" Exception

Tags: android

I'm having some issues with sending data from an Android client to a desktop server over TCP via wifi. The emulator works fine, but on the actual phone, the connection cannot be established. A "socket not connected" exception was thrown.

I have attached my code below. Any help please? Many thanks!

// CODE inside an Activity

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
   switch (item.getItemId()) {
   case R.id.send:
           sendMessage();
           return true;
   /// ...other items
   }
}

private void sendMessage() {
   String serverAddr = "18.xxx.xx.xxx";
   Socket socket = null;
   try {
           socket = new Socket(serverAddr, 4444);  // EXCEPTION HAPPENS HERE
   } catch (Exception e) {
           //show exception on screen
   }

   String message = "some message";
   try {
           PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
           out.println(message);
   } catch (Exception e) {
           //show exception on screen
   } finally {
           socket.close();
   }
}
```

Comment: the problem is that you do not know what type of failure you have..rewrite the code to use Socketfactory as Socketfactory gives a type of failure so that you know which failure you have than retest to see what type of failure you have..it might be connection, timeout, or etc..

Comment: @Fred: Thanks Fred. Problem solved according to your suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

Your serverAddr should not be a string but be a InetAddr . 
Use InetAddr.getByName("18.x.x.x")

Answer (score 0):

You can go through Exception handling in java using: - http://source.android.com/source/code-style.html#java-language-rules.Hope you can find solution.

Answer (score 0):

Server Address Should be your Server local address in the network .
Also you need to configure router "PORT FORWORDING" to send all packets from port 4444 and forward it to your server local ip. Also both phone and server pc should be connected to the same WiFi network.